# Redirecting a URL to a folder in DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, localhost

I have three folders in my document root -

```
localhost/myMainProject/   
localhost/myMainProjectSubdomain/  
localhost/myThirdProject/
```

I want to do the achieve following URL mapping -

```
www.mymainproject.com ---> localhost/myMainProject/
mysubdomain.mymainproject.com ---> localhost/myMainProjectSubdomain/
www.mythirdproject.com ---> localhost/myThirdProject/
```

I tried to change my hosts file to :

```
127.0.0.1/myMainProjectSubdomain mysubdomain.mymainproject.com
127.0.0.1/myMainProject www.mymainproject.com 
127.0.0.1/myThirdProject www.mythirdproject.com
```

But this doesnt work. I think I have to create some .htaccess file or something somewhere but have no idea how that works.

Is this possible ? Please guide me on how this can be achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for www.mymainproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mymainproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myMainProject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myMainProject/$1 [L]

# for mysubdomain.mymainproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.mymainproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myMainProjectSubdomain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myMainProjectSubdomain/$1 [L]

# for www.mythirdproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mythirdproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myThirdProject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myThirdProject/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick response. This works for the main URL, ie.  www.mymainproject.com, mysubdomain.mymainproject.com and www.mythirdproject.com are correctly mapped. However, when I try something like www.mymainproject.com/index.php it wont work. I have to add www.mymainproject.com/myMainProject/index.php (I am using CodeIgniter but I dont think this would matter)

Comment: @cyclotrojan The rule specifically matches *everything* after the slash (using the `^(.*)$` regular expression) and rewrites it to `/myMainProject/` (appending it using the **$1** back reference). So you can go to `www.mymainproject.com/qweadasdwqdasd` and it'll rewrite the request to `/myMainProject/qweadasdwqdasd` even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I still have this mapping in my hosts file 127.0.0.1 mysubdomain.mymainproject.com
127.0.0.1 www.mymainproject.com 
127.0.0.1 www.mythirdproject.com

Comment: @cyclotrojan your /etc/hosts has no effect on why `^(.*)$` isn't matching `/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. I had to create another .htaccess file inside my codeigniter folder to enable clean URLs :) Now  www.mymainproject.com/welcome points correctly to localhost/myMainProject/welcome Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally how I got it to work :

In hosts file -

```
127.0.0.1 mysubdomain.mymainproject.com
127.0.0.1 www.mymainproject.com 
127.0.0.1 mymainproject.com 
127.0.0.1 www.mythirdproject.com
127.0.0.1 mythirdproject.com
```

In Document root - (as mentioned in the accepted answer)

```
RewriteEngine On

# for www.mymainproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mymainproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myMainProject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myMainProject/$1 [L]

# for mysubdomain.mymainproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.mymainproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myMainProjectSubdomain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myMainProjectSubdomain/$1 [L]

# for www.mythirdproject.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mythirdproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myThirdProject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myThirdProject/$1 [L]
```

Inside my project folder, I had to create another .htaccess file -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|images|stylesheets|javascript|captcha|js|css|table-images)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now the URLs map perfectly !!
Eg.

> www.mymainproject.com/welcome --> localhost/myMainProject/welcome